# turn off gzip encoding for site in varnish config

Tags: linux, varnish, gzip

I am attempting to turn off the gzip encoding for a specific website which is backed by a load balancer in order for some developers to troubleshoot something. I have already adjusted the apache config to disable mod_deflate on the web server (by commenting out `LoadModule deflate_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so`) and set my hosts file on my machine to bypass the load balancer, but the site was still using gzip. This led me to believe the change may need to be made in the varnish configuration. From what I've found in research, I need to change the parameter for `http_gzip_support` to `false`. I do not, however, see anything related to gzip in `/etc/varnish/default.vcl`.

I am running Ubuntu, using Varnish 3.0.5.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than turning it off site-wide, why not have the developers make requests that don't request compression?  If the `Accept-Encoding` header isn't set in the request, the server shouldn't be sending back compressed data.